# Link opens in new window instead of new tab even after adding target="_blank" when the site is developed in sitecore 8

Tags: html

In Sitecore-8 CMS all external links opens in a new window rather than a new tab in IE 10 and IE 9 even after providing target="_blank" in the href tag.

Please give us some solution.

Comment: Are these links the Generic Link field in Sitecore and displayed using <sc:Link> control?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with you IE settings, do this:

```
Press Alt + X on your keyboard
Click Internet Options
Click Settings under Tabs
Under When a pop-up is encountered:, select Always open pop-ups in a new tab
Under Open links form other programs in:, select A new tab in the current window
```

And then then try running your code again!

Comment: I tried but didn't work. Please provide some solution.